# Use the same request for put and post in OpenAPI

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Using OpenApi and openapi-generator-maven. I want to have one request section for `PUT` and `POST` of the same entity, is it possible?
I tried to do something like that:

```yaml
    entities:
      post:
        tags:
          - EntityV1
        operationId: saveEntity
        parameters:
          - $ref: 'v1/parameters.yaml#/path/storeId'
        requestBody:
          name: save_config_request
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: 'components.yaml#/saveRequest'
        responses:
          200:
            ...
      put:
        tags:
          - EntityV1
        operationId: updateEntity
        parameters:
          - $ref: 'v1/parameters.yaml#/path/storeId'
          - $ref: 'v1/parameters.yaml#/path/entityId'
        requestBody:
          name: update_config_request
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: 'components.yaml#/updateRequest'
        responses:
          200:
            description: update succeeded
          ...
```

And tried to first do this in my service.yaml file:

```yaml
      /v1/stores/{store_id}/entities:
        $ref: 'v1/requests.yaml#/entities'
```

and also this:

```yaml
      /v1/stores/{store_id}/entities:
        $ref: 'v1/requests.yaml#/entities'
      /v1/stores/{store_id}/entities/{entity_id}:
        $ref: 'v1/requests.yaml#/entities'
```

If I have only the first path then the build succeeds, but I can not make the `PUT` request and the service returns a 404. If I try reusing the request body with both definitions, then I get this build error:

> -Could not find components/schemas/updateRequest in contents of ./v1/requests.yaml

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: Note the tag [api] has the instruction "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `components` section.

It seems like you have separate files where you are referencing components from.

If you have multiple files, you can achieve it like this:

###### openapi.yaml

```yaml
/entities:
  post:
    tags:
      - EntityV1
    operationId: saveEntity
    parameters:
      - $ref: 'v1/parameters.yaml#/path/storeId'
    requestBody:
      $ref: 'components.yaml#/requestBodies/update_request'
    responses:
      '200':
        ...
  put:
    tags:
      - EntityV1
    operationId: updateEntity
    parameters:
      - $ref: 'v1/parameters.yaml#/path/storeId'
      - $ref: 'v1/parameters.yaml#/path/entityId'
    requestBody:
      $ref: 'components.yaml#/requestBodies/update_request'
    responses:
      '200':
        description: update succeeded
      ...
```

##### components.yaml

```yaml
requestBodies:
  update_request:
    description: a multi-use request body
    content:
      'application/json':
        schema:
          type: object
          properties: {... add your properties here for the request payload}
```